# Equivalent Data Type in Java for Datetime in Kusto

Tags: java, azure-data-explorer, kusto-java-sdk

I am using Datetime in Kusto. What should be the data type in Java to ingest to Kusto as datetime?

Example: I am setting `StartTime:datetime, EndTime: datetime` as column type. I have tried Date as type in java but Kusto is not accepting this type:

```
import java.util.Date;
    public Date startTime;
    public Date endTime;
```

What should be the type instead?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "Kusto is not accepting the type"? What type of action are you trying to do and what error do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### tl;dr

Likely [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), or else [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

### Kusto `datetime`

In [Kusto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_Data_Explorer), the [`datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/datetime) data type represents a moment as seen in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), that is, a date and time-of-day with an [offset from UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero hours-minutes-seconds. The `datetime` type resolves to 100-nanosecond units.

### `java.time.Instant`

In Java, the `Instant` class represents a moment as seen in UTC. This type has a finer resolution, down to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

So, the `Instant` class in Java is the natural counterpart to `datetime` in Kusto.

### `java.time.OffsetDateTime`

However, your Java driver for Kusto may use another type, if it abides by the [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) specification. JDBC is oriented to the [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) standard. Per that standard, the Java class `OffsetDateTime` is mapped to columns of a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

An `OffsetDateTime` is similar to `Instant` in that in represents a date and time-of-day as seen in a particular offset from UTC. In `OffsetDateTime`, the offset can be any number of hours-minutes-seconds whereas in `Instant` the offset is always zero.

Also, `Instant` is the basic building-block class within the *java.time* framework. In contrast, `OffsetDateTime` is more flexible including more options for parsing & generating text representations.

I am not a Kusto user, and [their documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-java) is lacking, so I do not know which Java class your driver will map to a Kusto `datetime`. But I would guess mostly likely an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), or otherwise an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

### Conversion

You can easily convert between the two.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

… and:

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

Be aware that `java.util.Date` shown in your Question is one of the terribly flawed date-time classes from the earliest versions of Java. These legacy classes were years ago supplanted entirely by the modern *java.time* classes defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) for Java 8+.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean when you run a query:

```java
KustoOperationResult result = queryClient.execute("Data", "AllDataTypes");
KustoResultSetTable table = result.getPrimaryResults();
```

The way to retrieve a column is to iterate over the rows, and grab it by its type.
For date, you can either have it as `java.sql.Date' or 'java.time.LocalDateTime', depends on which method you call:

```java
while (table.hasNext) {
   table.next(); // advances to the next row
   java.sql.Date d = table.getDate("your-date-column"); 
   java.time.LocalDateTime d2 = table.getKustoDateTime("your-date-column");
}
```